# OleDb Exception (0X8001010D)

Tags: c#, oledbconnection

While running my C# application i have an error containing the following exception text:

```
System.Data.OleDb.Exception (0x8001010D): An outgoing call cannot be made since the application is dispatching an input-synchronous call.
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(OleDbConnectionString constr, DataSourceWrapper& datasrcWrapper)
at ...
```

**Note:** the computer i used to write application code installed Access 2013, and the application runs perfect, but the problem when i run the application at computers installed Access 2007 this error observes. 
What i should do, install Access 2013 on these computers or change the OleDB connection statement?

Comment: Can you post part of your code (the connection string part) please?

Comment: come on! share a piece of your code.